# Existence of a holomorphic connection implies existence of a flat connection

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, holomorphic-bundles

Let $E$ be a holomorphic vector bundle on a complex manifold $X$, and let $D: E \to E \otimes \Omega_X$ be a holomorphic connection on $E$ i.e.
$$
D(fs) = s\otimes \partial(f)+ fD(s),
$$
for any local holomorphic function $f$ and local section $s$. Locally such conections look like 
$$
D = \partial + A,
$$
where $A$ is a holomorphic section of $\operatorname{End}(E)\otimes \Omega_X$.

If $D$ is a holomorphic connection on $E$ then $D+\bar{\partial}$ is an "ordinary" connection on $E$.

How can one show that if $E$ admits a holomorphic connection then it admits a flat connection? In other words there is $B \in\operatorname{End}(E)\otimes \Omega_X$ s.t.
$$
(\bar{\partial} +D+B)^2=0.
$$

Comment: Why do you think this is true? For example, the Chern classes of a holomorphic vector bundle generally do not vanish. (By the Chern-Weil formula, the cohomology class is independent of connection.)

Comment: Chern classes of a holomorphic vector bundle with holomorphic connection all vanish. At least if we assume that $X$ is Kahler.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wasn't paying enough attention. Do you know [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-10/S0002-9939-98-04429-3/S0002-9939-98-04429-3.pdf)?

Comment: No, I did not know about that paper. But in that paper more subtle question is solved: existence of a compatible flat connection. I want much less, any flat connection on the same holomorphic bundle will be enough.

Comment: Dear @TedShifrin,I came across the same question while reading Huybrechts' Complex Geometry.Now,we have two propositions : 1.A holomorphic vector bundle $E$ admits a holomorphic connection iff its Atiyah class $A(E)\in H^1(X,\Omega_X\otimes End(E)) $ is trivial.2.For the curvature $F_\nabla$ of the Chern connection on  an hermitian holomorphic vector bundle $(E,h)$ one has $[F_\nabla]=A(E)\in H^1(X,\Omega_X\otimes End(E))$.So now, if we know $A(E)=0$,how can we find a vanishing $F_\nabla$ over $X$?Could you provide me some thoughts?Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear @TedShifrin,I forgot to replenish the origin text in Huybrechts' book.In Remark 4.2.20,he says: *Later we will see that Atiyah class $A(E)$ is related to the curvature of $E$.Roughly,a holomorphic connection on a vector bundle $ E$ over a compact manifold exists,i.e.$A(E)=0$,iff the bundle is flat.*

Comment: @Steve Huybrechts's comment is indeed confusing, and personally, I don't think that is true. Vanishing of curvature tensor is a strong condition. Maybe he just mean the item 2 as you mentioned.